# html data attribute stripped from my code in Apache

Tags: jquery, apache

I spent lot of time, but could not figure it out, I created another simple html file :
http://justpaste.it/j905

locally it's fine, but always I got undefined when run it under Apache.

I will appreciate if you can give me an idea on how to find a solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions to a human-readable format ;)

Comment: Also the problem is because the HTML in your fiddle is invalid - `tr` elements ***must*** be within a `table`. Fix that and your `data` attributes appear fine: http://jsfiddle.net/b2y9Ls5o/1/

Comment: I know tr must be in a table, I just copied the part that has the problem, why data attributes disappear when running my code in Apache ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Apache, but the only suggestion I can think of is that Apache is being clever and deciding that your page is not HTML5 and removing it for you. Which [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp) are you using at the top of your page? It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I have : <!DOCTYPE html> in the top of the jsp file, but noticed that source code from Apache changed to :  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: That's more than likely your problem then! You must have a setting somewhere overriding it. Out of interest, which browser are you testing with?